# How to define relational operators and keywords in flex

Tags: c, flex-lexer, lex, lexical-analysis

I'm trying to build a lex program to recognize tokens. How can I define relational operators (less than, greater than,...) and keywords (if, then, else) in flex in the declarations section inside: "%{ %}" using the C #define statements.

Answer (score 0):

lex ([flex](http://dinosaur.compilertools.net/flex/manpage.html)) knows about *tokens* which are matched using regular expressions.  It does not do C preprocessor substitutions in the text of the regular expressions (called *patterns*).  C `#define` statements which you may put within the `%{` and `%}` markers may help with the actions that you can write for each expression.